# PHP exec doesn't run my script as intended

Tags: php, c, linux, embedded, plc

Hey fellow programmers,

I'm working on my bachelor's project and got into a bit of a problem.

The goal is to create a web app, that can operate and modify I/O of a WAGO PLC 750-8202 (you can imagine it as some kind of industrial Raspberry PI) running an embedded linux with a lighttpd web server. I've made some C scripts that utilize DAL(HAL) functions the PLC provides.

Now I want to link it with my web application/site. I have a simple PHP page (ignore the button, it does nothing):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <button value="CLICK ME">CLICK ME</button>
<?php
echo system("kbusdemo1");
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I'm calling the kbusdemo1 script. It's supposed to print the values of digital inputs. If I call it from a SSH terminal connected to my PLC as root, it works just fine. However, if I call it from the PHP site (as shown above), it executes BUT it doesn't show digital input values, but instead an error saying "No device found on KBUS". You can see the exact line in the code below.

KBUS is a bus where all the input/output modules of the PLC are connected. Basically it looks like it doesn't execute the functions provided by the PLC developer correctly.

Here is the code written in C (kbusdemo1.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <dal/adi_application_interface.h>

#define KBUS_MAINPRIO 40

int
main(void)
{
    // vars for ADI-interface
    tDeviceInfo deviceList[10];          // the list of devices given by the ADI
    size_t nrDevicesFound;               // number of devices found
    size_t nrKbusFound;                  // position of the kbus in the list
    tDeviceId kbusDeviceId;              // device ID from the ADI
    tApplicationDeviceInterface * adi;   // pointer to the application interface
    uint32_t taskId = 0;                 // task Id
    tApplicationStateChangedEvent event; // var for the event interface of the ADI
    int AnWriteSelect, AnReadSelect, i, j, k, DigWriteOffset = 32, DigReadOffset = 32, vyber;
    int DigWrite[8] = {0}, DigRead[8] = {0};
    char DigWriteBuff[8];
    int16_t AnRead, AnWrite;
    bool loop = false;

    struct sched_param s_param;

    // program start
    //printf("**************************************************\n");
    //printf("***             KBUS test app                  ***\n");
    //printf("**************************************************\n");

    // clear process memory
    memset(DigWrite, 0, sizeof(DigWrite));
    memset(DigWriteBuff, 0, sizeof(DigWriteBuff));
    memset(DigRead, 0, sizeof(DigRead));

    // connect to ADI-interface
    adi = adi_GetApplicationInterface();

    // init interface
    adi->Init();

    // scan devices
    adi->ScanDevices();
    adi->GetDeviceList(sizeof(deviceList), deviceList, &nrDevicesFound);

    // find kbus device
    nrKbusFound = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < nrDevicesFound; ++i)
    {
        if (strcmp(deviceList[i].DeviceName, "libpackbus") == 0)
        {
            nrKbusFound = i;
            printf("KBUS device found as %i\n", i);
        }
    }

    // kbus not found > exit
    if (nrKbusFound == -1)
    {
        printf("No device found on KBUS\n");
        adi->Exit(); // disconnect ADI-Interface
        return -1; // exit program
    }

    // switch to RT Priority
    s_param.sched_priority = KBUS_MAINPRIO;
    sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, &s_param);
    printf("Switch to RT priority 'KBUS_MAINPRIO'\n");

    // open kbus device
    kbusDeviceId = deviceList[nrKbusFound].DeviceId;
    if (adi->OpenDevice(kbusDeviceId) != DAL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Opening KBUS device failed\n");
        adi->Exit(); // disconnect ADI-Interface
        return -2; // exit program
    }
    //printf("Otevření KBUS zařízení OK\n");


    // set application state to "Unconfigured" to let library drive kbus by them selve.
    // In this mode library set up a thread who drive the kbus cyclic.
    event.State = ApplicationState_Unconfigured;   
    if (adi->ApplicationStateChanged(event) != DAL_SUCCESS)
    {
        // Set application state to "Unconfigured" failed
        printf("Setting Unconfigured application state failed\n");  
        adi->CloseDevice(kbusDeviceId); // close kbus device    
        adi->Exit(); // disconnect ADI-Interface        
        return -3; // exit programm
    }
    printf("Unconfigured application state OK\n");

    adi->WatchdogTrigger();
    adi->ReadStart(kbusDeviceId, taskId);
    for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
    {
            adi->ReadBool(kbusDeviceId,taskId,DigReadOffset,(int*) &DigRead[k]);
        DigReadOffset++;
    }
        adi->ReadEnd(kbusDeviceId, taskId);
    for(k = 0; k < 8; k++)
        printf("%d ",DigRead[k]);
    printf("\n \n");
    DigReadOffset = 32;


    adi->CloseDevice(kbusDeviceId);
    adi->Exit();
    return 0;
}
```

So, the question is, am I using a correct method? Is PHP exec suitable for this kind of application? If so, any idea where I'm doing something wrong?

I understand that it's a device specific problem. I'm currently out of ideas and any hint that can point me in the right direction is priceless.

Thank you for your time.

---

EDIT

Ok, I tried editing sudoers with

```
sudo nano /etc/sudoers
```

Visudo is not implemented in the PLC linux system. I changed it to the code posted below, but if I try to run it as you suggested (with su www), it still doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for you suggestions.

```
# sudoers file.
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# Defaults specification

# Runas alias specification

# User privilege specification
root  ALL=(ALL) SETENV: ALL
admin ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/config-tools/get_user_info
user ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/config-tools/get_user_info
www ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

# Uncomment to allow people in group wheel to run all commands
# and set environment variables.
# %wheel  ALL=(ALL) SETENV: ALL

# Same thing without a password
# %wheel  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: SETENV: ALL

# Samples
# %users  ALL=/sbin/mount /cdrom,/sbin/umount /cdrom
# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Comment: Possibly because your PHP script doesn't run as root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you run the script as root, it has another rights than user under which lighthttpd is running.

- set appropiate rights for user or group (www or www-data, see lighthttpd config)
- check running under this user, in console for switch from root use

  # su - www

Comment: I needed to set appropriate rights, now it's working. Thanks a lot!